# Instead of scanning multiple ports I'm scanning only one and when port is closed my app closes

Tags: c#, winforms, tcpclient, asynccallback

I'm trying to scan multiple ports at once using asynchronymous scanning. The problem is that I can only display the first working port and then waiting like 20 seconds my app is closing with out telling me that the port is closed.

What could be wrong with this code?

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int port = 80; port < 100; port++)
    {
        ScanPort(port);
    }
}

private void ScanPort(int port)
{
    var client = new TcpClient();

    try 
    {
        client.BeginConnect(IPAddress.Parse("74.125.226.84"), port, new AsyncCallback(CallBack), client);
    } 
    catch (SocketException) 
    {
        client.Close();
    }
}

private void CallBack(IAsyncResult result)
{
    var client = (TcpClient)result.AsyncState;

    client.EndConnect(result);

    if (client.Connected)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            txtDisplay.Text += "open2" + Environment.NewLine;
        });
    }
    else
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            txtDisplay.Text += "closed2" + Environment.NewLine;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say your app is closing? Also, what output exactly do you get?

Comment: @Scott Smith, yes, just closing no errors, no warnings. The output is `open` because I know that the port I'm starting with (80) is open.

Comment: You need to wrap your code in the CallBack function with a try catch and handle the SocketExceptions. The subsequent connections are being refused most likely because the port is not open. This is occurring on the EndConnect call.

Comment: @Scott Smith, this fixes unexpected closing, but I still have a problem with checking only first port.

Comment: Your code is checking all of the ports. I tested this out myself and the endpoint is not listening on other ports besides 80 so the connections are being refused.

Comment: @Scott Smith, yes I know. I should have added that I do know that only 80 port is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your callback method, I would make sure close the connection and dispose of the TcpClient.  Also TcpClient.EndConnect(IAsyncResult) can also throw exceptions.  I also do not see where capturing the port number for display to the user.  I would write the callback something like this.

*Edit: I didn't actually compile or execute my code (sorry).  I also found this other article that shows how to create a port scanner in C#, http://www.dijksterhuis.org/building-a-simple-portscanner-in-c/  There is a comment in this post stating,*

> There is a gotcha here : The .NET implementation of TCPClient.Close() function does not actually close the connection properly. So we need to do the additional steps of obtaining the stream representing the connection and closing this as well before calling TCPClient.Close.

```
private void CallBack(IAsyncResult result) 
{ 
    var client = (TcpClient)result.AsyncState; 
    bool connected = false;

    try
    {
        client.EndConnect(result);
        connected = client.Connected;
    }
    catch (SocketException)
    {
    }
    catch (ObjectDisposedException)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        if (client.Connected)
        {
            client.Close();
        }

        client.Dispose();
    }

    if (connected) 
    { 
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate 
        { 
            txtDisplay.Text += "open2" + Environment.NewLine; 
        }); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate 
        { 
            txtDisplay.Text += "closed2" + Environment.NewLine; 
        }); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Ok, I copied and pasted your code just to see if it works. first error comes up that cannot access: client.Dispose(); due protection level. let me see what happens with out it.

Comment: First, the code output seem right. port 80 was open and rest was closed. but then I have changed to start with port 79 which i know is closed and the output states it's open and doesn't show that port 80 is open and the rest is closed.

Comment: @NewHelpNeeder Your assessment is incorrect. The one you see stating it is open is for 80. Your are doing async code so you see 80 immediately and it takes 20 seconds to see output for the others which includes 79.

Comment: @Scott Smith, I changed line to: `int port = 79; port < 100; port++` in for loop so first I should see the closed then open then rest closed, right? I see first open, rest closed.

Comment: Oh, I get it, since port 80 is closed and it's async then I see 80 port open and rest closed because their status checking is slower. Ok, I see.

Comment: PS. instead of using closing and appropriate steps to close connections wouldn't I just use using statement?